# Access instance variables from default method in inner interface

Tags: java, static, java-8

Given that we now have `default` methods on an `interface` in Java 8, is there any way that we can access instance methods from a parent class in a inner (non `static`) `interface`, for example something like this:

```
public class App {

    int appConst = 3;

    public interface MyInstanceInterface {

        default int myAppConst() {
            return appConst;
        }
    }
}
```

My `interface` is not `static` and therefore it *should* be able to access `appConst` in the `App.this` context.

This code fails with the following compile error:

> error: non-static variable appConst cannot be referenced from a static context

**Why?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The reason for this is [JLS §8.5.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.5.1):

> A member interface is implicitly static (§9.1.1). It is permitted for the declaration of a member interface to redundantly specify the static modifier.

An inner `interface` can never be non-`static`. The declaration:

```
public class App {

    ...      

    public interface MyInterface {

        ...

    }
}
```

Is exactly equivalent to:

```
public class App {

    ...      

    public static interface MyInterface {

        ...

    }
}
```

*N.B: this has always been the case, and merely remains unchanged in Java 8.*

Comment: 8.1.3 is about classes. The behavior is actually described in 8.5.1: _ A member interface is implicitly static_